# recarding the properties file issue in java

Tags: java

presently in our java project we are using properties file to store the db credentials but any one can open and see that  credentials. Is there any way to store the value in a secure manner

## db properties

```
url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.54:3306/sms_us_s49?user=root&password=Mys@lAdm!
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: recarding the properties file issue in java

Answer (score 0):

*Jasypt provides the org.jasypt.properties.EncryptableProperties class for loading, managing and transparently decrypting encrypted values in .properties files, allowing the mix of both encrypted and not-encrypted values in the same file.
http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html*